# How to properly set specific PHP version used by Apache on Arch?

Tags: php, php-fpm, php7, arch-linux, nextcloud

So it appears that after a recent Arch system upgrade, my NextCloud server no longer works, currently giving me `"This version of Nextcloud is not compatible with > PHP 7.4. You are currently running 8.0.1."`

`php -v` now gives me `PHP 8.0.1` but i do have also have `/usr/bin/php7` (PHP 7.4.14) installed.

I basically just use PHP for `nextcloud` *(cur. v20.0.6-1)*, trough Apache + `php-fpm`

So i'm wondering what would be the proper "arch way", or workaround, to opt to rather continue using `php7` ? *(at least for the time being)*

Any way i could e.g downgrade the `php` and `php-fm` packages or something? *(preferably without it breaking something else)* . Or should i perhaps just rather await for a new `nextcloud` version to be compatible with current `php`version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally got NextCloud working again. And i figured i'd post some notes about how here, for my own future reference, and as tip for anyone else perhaps facing the same problem.

I apologize for not making the answer more detailed and way less messy. But i messed around so much i'm not even entirely sure if i'm perhaps missing one or more points in this.

**Installed Arch packages:**

```
php7 php7-apache php7-apcu php7-fpm php7-gd php7-igbinary php7-imagick php7-imap php7-intl php7-memcache php7-memcached php7-pgsql php7-redis php7-sqlite php7-xsl
```

*(These might depend on the Nextcloud apps desired/installed See [Nextcloud prerequisites](https://docs.nextcloud.com//server/stable/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html#prerequisites-for-manual-installation) for more detail.)*

**Check (and edit) */etc/php7/php.ini* for required php extensions:**

Add any missing php extensions/modules.

```
$ php7 -m  # confirm that the needed modules are enabled

[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gmp
hash
iconv
igbinary
imagick
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
redis
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

**Enable and start *php-fpm7*:**

```
$ sudo systemctl enable php-fpm7.service && sudo systemctl start php-fpm7.service
```

*(note: I also disabled `php-fpm.service`since nextcloud is the only thing used in my case, though this might be unnecessary)*

**Add this to the Apache virtualhost running nextcloud:**

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm7/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

**Fix [nextcloud systemd cronjobs](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/20/admin_manual/configuration_server/background_jobs_configuration.html#systemd):**

Simply change `php` to `php7` in `/etc/systemd/system/nextcloudcron.service`.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php7 -f /srv/http/nextcloud/cron.php
```

**Restart the necessary services, or reboot server.**

That should do it..I think..

Comment: could you revisit, review then edit your answer, please?